# Oracle eText rtf template and Extended Function

Tags: oracle11g, rtf, bi-publisher, oracle-fusion-apps

I am working on Oracle 11g NACHA eText rtf template and i am facing problems while creating this template as per Bank needs. I need help while using **substring** extended function in column **Originating DFI Identification**.

My function is like this: substr(BankAccountNumber,1,8)

But when, I test the template using template viewer i got following erorr:
**[112616_130010213][][PROCEDURE] Log Level is changed to PROCEDURE
[112616_130011163][][ERROR] expression: is invalid** 
Time: 4.706 sec.
FO Formatting failed.
End of Process.

Anyone here can help me with this please ?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax looks correct, try making it uppercase. Check to see if that tag contains any data, and that the datatype is Alpha in the etext template.

Comment: datatype is Alpha, does this make the syntax different from the one, I already wrote ?

Comment: if its alpha, nothing required. Check the xdo logs and the temporary xsl file created during report running to further debug this issue. If you can, post a snippet of that xml for us.